# How to store a large number of 2d triangle and retrieve them efficiently using range query

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a large list of 2d triangle (in the order of millions) and I need to store them and retrieve them efficiently using range serach queries.

I have heard about KD Trees, Quad Trees, just wanted to be sure, is there a better one to store 2d triangles, I know that the above mentioned are generic one, is there any thing better for 2d triangle.

I am working with C#.

Comment: KD trees and quad trees are used to index spatial data, they can be used for this problem if you figure out how you will store triangles overlapping into 2 regions, i,e., not falling into 1 leaf node

Comment: Also when you say 'retrieve', what form does the querying take? "Find me all the triangles that use this vertex"? "Find me all the triangles that cover this point"? "Find me all the triangles that completely cover this region"? etc

Comment: BVH's are also quite good. The Box2D physics engine uses dynamic AABB trees. Many geographical databases use R-trees.

Comment: Triangles are in general not axis parallel, which is inconvenient for geometric data structures, that often rely on coordinate decoupling. So you wrap the triangles in their axis-aligned bounding box and restate the problem for boxes.

Answer (score 0):

My choice is a quadtree.

Each cell (a node in the tree) in the quadtree stores a container with the triangles that are fully **inside** the cell and cannot live in a smaller cell. A deeper, smaller, cell contains smaller triangles.

Query such as "triangles in this given bounding box" boils down to find the proper node in the tree (cell containing the box).

Query such as "triangles covering a given point" is a matter to find the cell (and its sub-cells) for that point, and then test every triangle in the containers for those cells.

Comment: how will you handle overlapping triangles and triangles inside triangles?

Comment: @gc7 What do you want to handle? Each triangle, overlapped or included, goes into the cell that minimally fits its bounding box.

Comment: so now the problem has changed from "store a large number of 2d triangle" to "store a large number of 2d rectangles", this won't improve the complexity of the queries.

Comment: @gc7 You may be true when most of triangles overlap. In that case there isn't any profit in using a structure or another. My answer is about normal data.

Comment: I tried with QuadTrees, where the 2d triangles are enclosed in a rectangle, but its too slow, Lets say, if we want to find how many triangles "touching" at a given point, When we retrieve the information from Quad Tree, you basically get rectangles, in those rectangles there are triangles, so all the triangles which we got from quad tree might not be "touching" the given point. Since, Quad Tree works with bounding box concept.

Comment: If your triangles don't overlap (much) then there should be just a bunch of triangles in each cell, and so few touching-tests are needed. I mean, before inserting in a cell a second triangle check that it doesn't fit in a sub-cell.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at R - trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). They are quite useful for range searches. Not sure if there are C# implementations available, but there are such for C++, for example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/introduction.html where you can find interesting benchmarks (tree building, queries)

I would also recommend to take a look at algorithm: "STR: A Simple and Efficient Algorithm for R-Tree Packing ". It produces quite good tree in case you want to minimize the overlapping.